# A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, byte, bytebuffer

Im new to c# client and server application, im working on a file upload client and server application.

i can successfully upload my file name and file data to the server from the client application. but when i try to implement a new textbox that allow the file upload client to enter his/her name and send the information together with the file name and file data when he/her click the send button.

client application.

```
 /* file name and file length */
            byte[] fName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName);
            byte[] fNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length); // length of file name
            clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length];                
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fName " + fName.Length);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fNamelen " + fNameLen.Length);
            fNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
            fName.CopyTo(clientData, 4);

            /* author name and author name length */
            byte[] aName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
            byte[] aNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(textBox2.Text.Length);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("aName " + aName.Length);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("aNamelen " + aNameLen.Length);
            authorData = new byte[9 + textBox2.Text.Length];
            aNameLen.CopyTo(authorData, 5);
            aName.CopyTo(authorData, 9);
```

server application

```
/* retriving of file name */
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error 1");
               fNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error 2 fNameLen " + fNameLen);
               string Filename = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 4, fNameLen);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error 3");
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("filename length " + fNameLen);
               receivedPath = @"C:\testfiles\" + Filename;
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("bytesREad1 " + bytesRead);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(receivedPath);

               /* retriving of author name */
               aNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 5);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error 4");
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("error  5");
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("author name length " + aNameLen);
               string authorName = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 9, aNameLen);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error 6");
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("author name " + authorName);
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("author name length " + aNameLen);
```

output window  and error given in bold:

- Error 1
- Error 2 fNameLen 12
- Error 3
- filename length 12
- bytesREad1 82
- C:\testfiles\Test1122.txt
- Error 4
- error  5
- author name length 829715301
- **A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
  occurred in mscorlib.dll**

thank you in advance.

Comment: where does it throw the exception??

Comment: The problem probably is this line `aNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 5);`. This 5 shouldn't be there. The correct number here is 4 + file name length.

Comment: exception is throw at this line string authorName = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 9, aNameLen);

Comment: i tried changing the `aNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 5);` to `aNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 4 + Filename.Length);` and `aNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 4 + fNameLen);` both also return null

Answer (score 1):

Things will be easier if you use BinaryReader / BinaryWriter.

Example:

**Client**

`fileContents` is a byte array.

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
writer.Write(fileName);
writer.Write(authorName);
writer.Write(fileContents.Length);
writer.Write(fileContents);

var data = stream.ToArray();  // send this data array to server
writer.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
```

**Server**

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(state.buffer);
var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

var fileName = reader.ReadString();
var author = reader.ReadString();
var fileContents = reader.ReadBytes(reader.ReadInt32());
reader.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
```