# Error in uploading a file using jQuery and Asp.Net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when I try to upload a file to server.

```
$('#But_Upload').click(function () {
            console.log("its working\n");
            var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../HANDLERS/Handler1.ashx",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: $('#upload').get(0).files.toString(),
                async: true,
                success: function (xhr) {
                    console.log("done");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My server code in C# handler is

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(context.ToString());
        try
        {
                HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = context.Request.Files.Get(0);
                var fileSavePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/upl") + httpPostedFile.FileName;
                httpPostedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
           }
        catch(Exception E)
        {  }
     }
```

I am getting the exception exactly at httpPostedFile line,I have been fighting with this for donkey age ,pls help.

Comment: Can you try this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880952/a-first-chance-exception-of-type-system-argumentoutofrangeexception-occurred-i

Comment: @ShrihariIyer - never say what exception/error message you get - we love to guess.

Comment: @onsjjss I am trying to upload an image .Got any other links?

Comment: Added solution. Try it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. There is an special change here for IE and so It works in all browsers. I guess you are facing the problem in IE only?

```
HttpPostedFile hpf = TryCast(Context.Request.Files(0), HttpPostedFile);

if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE")) {
    string[] files = hpf.FileName.Split(new char[] {"\\", c});
    MySerializedobject.FileName = files[(files.Length - 1)];
}
else {
    MySerializedobject.FileName = hpf.FileName;
}

string FileType = hpf.ContentType;
string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);
MySerializedobject.FileType = ("." + MySerializedobject.FileName.Split(".")[1]);
MySerializedobject.FileSize = hpf.ContentLength;
MySerializedobject.FileStream = hpf.InputStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];
        string savepath = "", tempPath = "";
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        tempPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourFilePath"];
        savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath);
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
        string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(postedFile.FileName) + extension;
        if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
        }
        System.IO.File.Delete(savepath + @"\" + filename);
        postedFile.SaveAs(savepath + @"\" + filename);
    }
```

on script:

```
$('#But_Upload').click(function () {
    var files = $("#<%=upload.ClientID %>").get(0).files;
    var test = new FormData();
    test.append(files[0].name, files[0]);
    console.log("its working\n");
    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../HANDLERS/Handler1.ashx",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: test,
        async: true,
        success: function (xhr) {
            console.log("done");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Getting an exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"} pls help